# Is it OK to ask questions about "Arduino compatible" micros (not clones)?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

There are many Arduino compatible micros and derivatives. I'm thinking specifically here of the [Spark Core](https://www.spark.io/).

It's not a clone, but uses the Arduino Sketch language and is wi-fi IoT oriented.

Are question related to Arduino compatible devices applicable here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are clone-specific questions on topic for this site?](http://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/15/are-clone-specific-questions-on-topic-for-this-site)

Comment: @sachleen I tried to make it clear in the question that this is **not** about Clones. But perhaps that was misunderstood. Arduino compatible or derivative devices are NOT clones and generally provide another level of functionality that Arduino official boards don't have.

Comment: OK I'm already confused, is there an official distinction between compatible vs. clone anywhere, or should I ask that as a question?

Comment: @ChrisO Here's clarification from Massimo Banzi in Arduino blog: http://blog.arduino.cc/2013/07/10/send-in-the-clones/#.Uw29BhDYPxw

Comment: @akellyirl Thanks that answers my question.

Comment: Arduino Compatible == Clone. I don't really know where you're going with this....

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson (Arduino Compatibles, Derivatives) != Clones... Derivatives extend the functionality of Arduino in a meaningful way. Quoting from Massimo Banzi's Blog (ref: above) "Derivatives. These are products that are derived from the Arduino hardware design but they innovate either by providing a different layout and features often to better serve a specific market. These are the products that have also helped Arduino become so ubiquitous." Yes, Compatibles are more "Hazy" territory but usually they also extend Arduino functionality in some way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal opinion is that the site should include within its scope all questions about:

- The official boards
- Questions about the official IDE
- The range of shields available
- Clones compatible with the IDE or the shields
- Devices/chips that are mentioned as being accessories for Arduino

So, **yes**.

Comment: The thing about compatible devices is that whilst they are compatible in some way such as using the Sketch commands and providing Analogue and Digital I/Os, they don't necessarily meet the criteria you laid out. Nevertheless Arduino Sketches can port to these devices and they can provide additional benefits to an Arduino user and therefore may complement an Arduino user's toolkit of devices. Possible question for "compatibles" may be: library porting; equivalent capability etc...

Comment: I would include more IDEs to be in-topic, such as the Eclipse and Visual Studion Arduino plugins, WinAVR etc. What do you think?

Comment: @Ricardo I would consider such questions to be borderline. For example, my question on using [RStudio with Arduino](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/38/how-do-i-communicate-with-the-uno-using-r-through-rstudio) is considered off-topic. I think this deserves its own discussion.

Comment: What about Bareduinos (ATMEGA chip on a breadboard), only with the IDE or programing it?

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson Are you the user who participated last time as well? Nice to see you here :) Bareduino questions would depend on the specific instance. Its hard to say without an example to gauge the type of questions to be expected. Although, if the question seems too EE specific, then EE.SE would be a better home.

Comment: @AsheeshR Yeah I didn't know that they did a second beta however I didn't sign up so I think I accidentally used a bug to sign up! Haha :) I hope this one doesn't go to waste either. I'm hoping for Moderator, or at least temporary but I think I'm too late. Oh well! It *does* take a ton of time.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson If you signed through the site link on the A51 page, then thats not a bug :) This beta seems to be quite different from last time. The questions are far more diverse. Anyways, I hope the same as well.

Comment: @AsheeshR But the question count is too low it seems like. 10ish per day... yikes. Working on that now. It is only private now but still... that's what really killed us last time

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Arduino has encouraged derivative hardware from the start. In the [introduction on the official site](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Introduction) they say:

> All Arduino boards are completely open-source, empowering users to build them independently and eventually adapt them to their particular needs.

(The above is taken from [this answer](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2436/31794).)