# Support for UDOO & Integrated Arduino Boards

Tags: discussion

Should we support tags of specific boards like the UDOO & Raspberry Pi? While a Raspberry Pi is different from an Arduino, the UDOO essentially is an Arduino Due and LInux Quad-core computer integrated into one device with shared processor communication. With that being said currently the UDOO has some issues with their IDE that doesn't allow certain Arduino Due related things to work properly. One of the main issues currently is that floats compile, but don't work properly on the Due and just crash the board.

Comment: Are you saying I won't be able to run a UDOO program on Due or a Due program on UDOO?

Comment: Raspberry Pi is definitely not on topic... try http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: These kind of questions can be asked now at: [Embedded Systems](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70800/embedded-systems) which is currently in private beta.

Comment: @sachleen once the float problem is fixed there will be no difference. Until then due code uploaded to the UDOO through their internal ide might not work. But if uploaded like a normal due it'll work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we could treat the UDOO as an "Arduino compatible" device, as per [this question](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-about-arduino-compatible-micros-not-clones). That means questions about the Arduino side of it would be relevant. However, if somebody is asking a wholly non-Arduino question about it (e.g. about its integrated graphics) then it should probably be considered off-topic.

The Raspberry Pi would seem to be off-topic as a general rule, as it's not trying to be Arduino compatible at all. Admittedly, there will probably be exceptions, e.g. where somebody is trying to program an Arduino from a Raspberry Pi (maybe via Gertboard or something).

Comment: What about the specific IDE glitches abs other UDOO issues even attempting to program the Due connected to it.

Comment: If it's a problem with UDOO's own IDE, then I suspect it's probably off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think most UDOO questions are on topic here... Unless the question is related to only the Arduino part of the system. If you can replace UDOO with Arduino in the question and it still makes sense, then it'd be on topic.

Problems with the UDOO IDE are totally off topic. If we allow people to ask any UDOO related questions, we will surely see some of those, but we can mark them as off topic, no problem.